# Secure connect with remote host and check

Tags: c, security, ssh, public-key

I need to write a program in C to check the occurrence of a computer's MAC address in a remote text file.

1. Are there any simple to use ssh libs which allow a program to connect to a remote host and check if a file contains something?
2. Or should I use the `system()` function to run `ssh` and simple commands on the remote host.
3. It should be secure, so probably I need to use public keys. Is it possible to use the same public key from different computers (each with my program)?

What I need is to check if the computer with the given MAC address (or other identifier) is allowed to do something. And this operation should be remote, so I could remotely enable/disable functionality.

Comment: http://www.openssh.com/?

Answer (score 2):

1) I don't know if it's simple, but there is http://www.libssh.org/ from, IIRC, the same folks who do cURL

2) Yes, you should probably do this via the "system function" of a shell script (or system/popen, if you absolutely need to have the results inside a C program), as that will save you a great deal of trouble reimplementing things.

3) Public keys, yes; and while it's possible to reuse public keys on multiple hosts/users, it's not good security practice; better would be generating a keypair for each user/host and then adding the public key to .ssh/authorized_keys on the machine you need to connect to. This means that revoking keys is simply removing a line in a single text file instead of regenerating a key for multiple hosts. However, if it's not security-sensitive, or if security just plain doesn't matter in this instance(!), then using a single key may not be too insane. That is, if you need multiple clients to check for existence on a single host; if not, please update your question to be clearer in this regard.